# Internet Explorer is messing Firefox & Chrome

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, windows-8.1

I there:

I am developing a system in PHP (language) using Apache as a web server (WAMPServer 5.4).

My site (located in http:\127.0.0.1) works fine in Firefox (my main browser).

I tested in Internet Explorer 10 and it works fine.  However, **if i try to open firefox when Internet Explorer is open (both pointing to the same website), Firefox delays 2 minutes to open the website**.

I though that it was some problem with the website, i checked with chrome & firefox but i was unable to replicate the same problem.

What i tried:

- Opening firefox then opening the site. Then, opening Internet Explorer and opening the site (it opens instantly). Then, turning back to firefox is refreshing the site. Result : delay 2 minutes.
- I tried the same with Chrome and Internet explorer and it happens the same. Chrome took 2 minutes to load the page.
- I tried to use Chrome and Firefox at the same time and it worked without any problem. (loads instantly).
- I opened Internet Explorer then Firefox and while firefox is trying to load the sime (the 2 minutes delays), i closed Internet Explorer. Result : firefox opened the site as fast i close internet explorer.

Apparently, Internet Explorer monopolyze my local connection.

What could be the cause?.

My spec:

Windows 8.1 64bits

Iexplorer 10 (no plugins active)

Firefox 28 beta (no plugins)

Chrome (latest)

WAMP Server.

DNS : 8.8.8.8 (no proxy).

Comment: If you open IE and point it at some OTHER site, does FF open your site at the expected speed?  Does it behave the same way if you open IE with-out add-ons enabled?  Does it behave the same way if you log into Windows as a different user?

Comment: IE10 isn't supported on Windows 8.1 so are you using windows 8.1 and IE11 or Windows 8.0 and IE10

Comment: yes is ie11 and i am unable to test in a different machine.